# How to cross-compile a binary for a Raspberry Pi written in Haskell in Ubuntu Linux?

Tags: ubuntu, cross-compilation, haskell

In the past I have compiled binaries for different architectures on an x86_x64 with the resulting target binary generated for a different architecture;

For instance the target binary might be for something like an [IA64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IA-64) or an ARM processor using `make` and `gcc` to compile C++ code and copying the resulting binary to a machine of that architecture type would (most of the time; assuming dependencies fulfilled) allow it run.

This is for different reasons, for instance on an [I64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IA-64)  architecture, I didn't want to install all the dependencies for compilation on a server.  And in the case of ARM (that it being for a Raspberry Pi) that it would take such a long time to compile.

Now that said, I haven't tired cross-compiling Haskell for ARM though the Haskell wiki appears to mention a [docker image](https://wiki.haskell.org/ARM) for doing so, and also a guide [here](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/wikis/building/cross-compiling-on-debian).  The guide seems a little out of date however, since I can't seem to download `build-dep` that it requires.

(I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS)

Also, what `dpkg --add-architecture <armxx>` command should I run to add [multiple architectures](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO#Configuring_architectures)?

Comment: Raspberry-Pi have `armhf` arch. `dpkg --add-architecture armhf` should work.

Comment: The place to start asking about this is [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) or AskUbuntu.  If you are waiting around here for a Pi user who works with Haskell and cross compiles on Ubuntu to drop by, you may be waiting for a long time.  You know the target platform, so just find out how to compile for that -- which actually there's not quite enough information to say what it should be, since you do not mention what model and OS you are using.

Comment: ...A baseline that should work on all Pis is armv6, but cross-compilers for that are hard to come by, so you may want to try for armv7 *if* your platform supports it.